# Stripe - Do I have to create a new PaymentIntent if user select a new payment method?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment

I'm using Stripe Payment Intent in my application. Right now I'm saving customers cards for future purchases. If let's say:

1. User go to checkout page.
2. A new Payment Intent with the user's default payment method is created.
3. The user changes the payment method to a new one during the checkout process.
4. User click the purchase button.

Do I have to update the payment intent every time the user select a new payment method during checkout process or can I use the same client secret from the payment intent I created the first time?

Comment: No, you would simply confirm the PaymentIntent with the new PaymentMethod client-side and it will just work and "override" the original PaymentMethod you had set.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, my code is currently working with the above flow. I just wanted to know if this is okay since I'm not creating neither updating the payment intent with the new selected payment method.